# por que sale el error S2531: Object is possibly 'null' en angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un pequeño formulario el cual quiero validar y tengo el siguiente Código, pero cuando lo ejecuto me manda el error y marca las lineas en .**errors** **.dirty** y en **.hasError**

> S2531: Object is possibly 'null'
>
> error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

17         <div *ngIf="loginForm!.get('usuario').errors && loginForm!.get('usuario').dirty">

como puedo solucionarlo?? , ademas de que quiero que al validarlo los input se pongan en color rojo si algo esta mal y esten en color verde cuando este todo OK, como puedo hacer eso?

html

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm!" (ngSubmit)="saveData" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" id="usuario" class="form-control" fromControlName="usuario">
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="text" id="contraseña" class="form-control" fromControlName="contraseña">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="loginForm!.get('usuario').errors && loginForm!.get('usuario').dirty">
        <p *ngIf="loginForm!.get('usuario').hasError('required')"> Campo Requerido</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm float-right"> Acceder</button>
</form>
```

component.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  implements OnInit{
  title = 'prueba2';

  
  loginForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public fb: FormBuilder
  ){
    
  }


  ngOnInit(){
      this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      usuario: ['', [Validators.required]],
      contraseña: ['', [Validators.required]],
    })
  }


  saveData(): void{
    console.log(this.loginForm.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Agrega `?` para corregir el error:

```
<p *ngIf="loginForm!.get('usuario')?.hasError('required')"> Campo Requerido</p>
```

Comment: Podrías editar tu respuesta y explicar por que agregar ? corregiría el error? de ese modo tu respuesta será de mejor calidad, mejor recibida y el autor de la pregunta podría aprender algo nuevo.

Comment: Bueno, el operador seguro `?` convierte una linea nula en `undefined`, lo que en angular (typescript-javascript) se transforma en `false`. Deja de ser posiblemente  nula a convertirse en false en caso de ser nula. En javascript esto no importa porque nulo se transforma en false por aquello de la "magia" de javascript, pero en el tipado de typescript no hay magia. Se espera que (a traves del compilador) corrijamos estos problemas antes de transpilarlo javascript.